# Filtering all but todays date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter out all but todays date using a macro (for the first time)
I want to create a macro or two that will show only rows using the date in which it's viewed. I've tried using the below, but it hides all rows containing a date

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("A10:A1000")
If cell.Value <= Date Then
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you setting the Hidden to False, it should be set to True to Hide: cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True. Also your code is checking cell.Value<=Date but the logic says 'all but today's date', so it should be cell.Value<>Date

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't need VBA to achieve this: you could use the filter functionality of Excel.

But if you want to do it via VBA this is a routine that does what you want:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub hideRowsIfNotDate(rgToCheckDate As Range, dateToBeVisible As Date)

Dim c As Range
For Each c In rgToCheckDate.Cells
    If IsDate(c.Value) Then 'just to be on the safe side if there is no date
        If c.Value <> dateToBeVisible Then
            'hide rows with different date
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            'show rows that match the date - just in case they were hidden before
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Advantage of this solution:

- you can pass different dates or ranges, therefore you can reuse the sub for different scenarios
- when you call the sub from your main code you simply know by reading the subs name what it is doing (w/o reading the code itself) - someone else (or you in 3 months) will appreciate that :-)

You will call the routine from your main code like this:

```vb
Public Sub test_hideRows()

Dim dateToBeVisible As Date
dateToBeVisible = Date  '= today

Dim rgToCheck As Range
Set rgToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:A1000")

hideRowsIfNotDate rgToCheck, Date

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain this: _you shouldn't use cell as variable name as it is a vba property_? I'm pretty sure [VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/language-reference) has nothing to do with _cell_. Also, I couldn't detect any _cell_ in the [Excel object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel). Sounds a bit unexpected. I would appreciate any link supporting your point of view.

Comment: @Vitalizzare you are right - there are `cells` and `activecell` but no cell property - I will delete that remark. It's more my personal way: not using variable names that are so close to properties, commands etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  `AutoFilter`? I assume that your data are stored in `Rows("10:1000")`, dates - in the column `A` and you have some headers in `Rows(9)`. With that in mind:

```
Set Source = Rows("9:1000")
Field = Range("A:A").Column
Value = Format(Date, Range("A10").NumberFormatLocal)
Source.AutoFilter Field, Value
```

If you have a custom date format, put that instead of `...NumberFormatLocal`